# SharedPreferences default value

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-adapter

Im using sharedpreferences in my adapter, but instead of getting the default values `-1` im getting `0` as default value. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
//constructor
public PlaylistAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Songs> songs) {
        activity = a;
        data = songs;
        prefs = a.getSharedPreferences("com.myapp",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(a);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_item, parent, false);
int playpos = prefs.getInt("posPlaying", -1);
//logs 0 as prefsvalue(should be -1) and the position
        Log.v("--", prefs.getInt("posPlaying", -1) + " " + position);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the posplaying does not hold any value then only the default value will come.so i think posplaying is holding the value as 0.check whether you intiated this value with 0 or some other calculations making this posplaying as 0.